# How can I gracefully shut down RawCap?

Tags: fiddler, pcap, packet-sniffers, analyzer, postman

I'm using [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) to capture packets sent from my dev machine (one app) to itself (another app). I can get it to write the captures to a file like so:

```
RawCap.exe 192.168.125.50 piratedPackets.pcap
```

...and then open the *.pcap file in Wireshark to examine the details. This worked when I called my REST method from Postman, but when using Fiddler's Composer tab to attempt the same, the *.pcap file ends up being empty. I think this may be because my way of shutting down RawCap was rather raw itself - I simply closed the command prompt. Typing "exit" does nothing while it's busy capturing.

How can I make like a modern-day Mansel Alcantra if I the captured packets sink to the bottom of the ocean before I can plunder the booty? How can I gracefully shut RawCap down so that it (hopefully) saves its contents to the log (*.pcap) file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RawCap is gracefully closed by hitting `Ctrl + C`. Doing so will flush all packets from memory to disk.

You can also tell RawCap to only capture a certain number if packets (using `-c` argument) or end sniffing after a certain number of seconds (using `-s` argument).
Here's one example using -s to sniff for 60 seconds:

`RawCap.exe -s 60 192.168.125.50 piratedPackets.pcap`

Finally, if none of the above methods is available for you, then you might wanna use the `-f` switch. By using `-f` all captured packets will be flushed to disk immediately. However, this has a performance impact, so you run a greater risk of missing/dropping packets when sniffing with the -f switch.

You can run `RawCap.exe --help` to show the available command line arguments. They are also documented here:
http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap

Comment: I don't see the command line arguments discussed anywhere on that page, or on any page directly linked to it.

Comment: ...also, just tried it from a mingw32 shell, and ctrl-c was *not* flushing the file. I was getting empty dumpfiles until I switched to using the Windows cmd.exe.

Comment: @t-e-d: You can see all available command line arguments by starting cmd.exe as Admin and running
`RawCap.exe --help`